# Make org-html export not escape special characters

Tags: org-mode, org-export, html

I'm writing an exporter for Remarkup: https://github.com/renatgalimov/org-phabricator.

It's similar to Markdown and based on `org-md` which itself is a modification of `ox-html`.

Whenever I export, some Unicode sequences get replaced by &something; HTML escape sequences, which is not necessary for remarkup.

I'm struggling to find, which function or setting I need to modify to skip the escaping.

Example:

```
   | ITEM                                | FOLLOW_CONFIG |
   |-------------------------------------+---------------|
   | \_  Enforcing particular resolution |               |
   | \_    No hotplug                    |               |
   | \_      HDMI mode auto              |               |
```

Result:

```
<table>

<tr>
<th>ITEM</th>
<th>FOLLOW<sub>CONFIG</sub></th>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>&ensp;&ensp;Enforcing particular resolution</td>
<td>&#xa0;</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;No hotplug</td>
<td>&#xa0;</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;HDMI mode auto</td>
<td>&#xa0;</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

I want to put   ([en-space](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2002)) instead of `&ensp;`s.

Thanks

Comment: Do they hurt anything? After all, you asked for these spaces: if you don't want them, why add `\_    `?

Comment: Remarkup can render en spaces without quoting. I want them to be there, but I don't want them to be replaced with `&ensp;`

Comment: The translation is done through the `org-entities` variable, but (partly because I don't know anything about `remarkup`) I don't really understand your workflow. Maybe the thing to do is to write a derived exporter (derived from the HTML exporter) where you somehow override the `org-entities` settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need any entitites, then you can customize (i.e. include/exclude) the export of entities via the `org-export-with-entities` variable.

To set the variable per buffer, you can include the `OPTIONS` keyword with the value `e:nil` at the beginning of your file/buffer.

```
#+OPTIONS: e:nil
```

source: https://orgmode.org/manual/Export-Settings.html (and the variable its docstring)

To exclude the `\_`    entitites specifically, you can override their values with the `org-entities-user` variable, e.g. as follows:

```lisp
(customize-set-value 'org-entities-user
                     (let (space-entities html-spaces (entity "_"))
                       (dolist (n (number-sequence 1 20) (nreverse space-entities))
                         (let ((spaces (make-string n ?\s)))
                             (push (list (setq entity (concat entity " "))
                                           (format "\\hspace*{%sem}" (* n .5))
                                           nil
                                           (setq html-spaces (concat " " html-spaces))
                                           spaces
                                           spaces
                                           (make-string n ?\x2002))
                                   space-entities)))))
```

(code taken from `org-entities` value and replaced `&ensp` by a single space)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I was searching for.